yolov10n.pt generates error during prediction
Based on following site: prediction based on yolo
I have implemented the following code:
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Build a YOLOv6n model from scratch
model = YOLO("yolov10n.pt")
results = model("human.png")

# Display the results
print(results[0].show())

where human.png is image like this:

but it generates  such error:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SCDown' on <module 'ultralytics.nn.modules.block' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\Artificial_Inteligence\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\ultralytics\\nn\\modules\\block.py'>

I have uninstalled and installed ultralytics again, but still  getting same  error.

Currently, Yolov10 is not available on ultralytics. You'd need to install yolov10 from the original source. Then you can run your code block.

Install yolov10 git repository by using this command:
pip install git+https://github.com/THU-MIG/yolov10.git

Also install huggingface-hub by using this command:
pip install huggingface-hub

These installations resolve this error.

Update new version can solve it:
pip install ultralytics==8.2.45

